# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf post list

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to post a list of strings to my controller.
But it always only take the first selected value.

my thymeleaf html form:

```
<form action="/add" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="roleId">ID</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="roleId" name="id" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rolePrivileges">Privileges</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="rolePrivileges" name="privileges" multiple="multiple" size="10" required="required">
            <option th:each="type : ${privilegesList}" th:value="${type}" th:text="${type}">Privilege</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
</form>
```

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSomething(Model model, @ModelAttribute("id") String id,
        @ModelAttribute("privileges") List<String> privileges) {
    // add something with a service
    return "redirect:/roles";
}
```

Comment: Try with `@RequestParam` instead of `@ModelAttribute`

Comment: Thomas Pawlitzki beat me by a few minutes, you should validate his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to Annotate the privilges with

```
@RequestParam("privileges")
```

It is not a ModelAttribute but you receive it from the request

Edit: two SO threads to better understand the difference between [@RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370581/spring-mvc-please-explain-difference-between-requestparam-and-modelattribute) and [@ModelAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021679/why-not-use-requestparam-instead-of-modelattribute).